# The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql

I import this table data into phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_books` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `seo_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `orginal_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `pub_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `long_desc` longtext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `counter` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8;
```

and i see this error :

> --
>
> -- Indexes for table `cms_books`
>
> --
>
> ALTER TABLE `cms_books`
>        ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `long_desc` (`long_desc`);
>       MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

In localhost i add `fulltext` for title and `long_desc` so this worked but when i import i see this error. how do fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your engine to MyISAM. FULL TEXT Search is supported after MySQL 5.6 in INNODB. You can check it over [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6713).

See the [MYSQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html):

> Full-text searches are supported for MyISAM tables only. (In MySQL 5.6
>   and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.)

Answer (score 3):

Simple find in sql file `ENGINE=InnoDB` replace with `ENGINE=MyISAM`

It's working fine for me.