# MYSQL Error Installing BuildEngine

Tags: php, mysql

error when installing Builder Engine

> Database Error: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT
>   indexes
> Query: ' CREATE TABLE `be_blog_posts` ( `id` int(11) NOT
>   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
>   DEFAULT NULL, `text` text DEFAULT NULL, `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT
>   '', `time_created` int(11) DEFAULT '0', `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT
>   '0', `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, `comments_allowed`
>   enum('yes','no','hide') DEFAULT 'yes', `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
>   `groups_allowed` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT
>   '', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FULLTEXT KEY `title_fulltext` (`title`) )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Comment: What version of mysql is installed?

Comment: 5.5.45-cll-lve - MySQL

Comment: You need at least 5.6.4 to have `FULLTEXT` indexes on `InnoDB` tables.

Comment: do'h i didnt even look at that now i feel stupid. thanks

Comment: Np. I had a quick look at the BuilderEngine site and didn't see any MySQL minimum version requirements which seems kinda rubbish if this is part of their install.

Comment: Ill see if i can get it to work with 5.6 and get back will be hand for others to know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817819/the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-fulltext-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run BuilderEngine's automatic installer your server must have mysql version 5.6 as a minimum requirement. Fulltext index support for the InnoDB engine was added to mysql version 5.6. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html

You can upgrade your version by the following these instructions for Ubuntu Linux.

First check your version of mysql, just to make sure that this is the issue.

```
mysql --version
```

If it returns 5.5 or lower, we know we need to upgrade. But first, let's make a backup of all of your databases. Requires your root password

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Now we can install mysql 5.6 (or 5.7).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

After installing it will ask you for your new root password. It may be wise to use the same as the previous one, but it's up to you.

Now we'll import our backed up databases.

```
mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
```

That's it. It may be worthwhile to test out the latest mysql 5.7 release, as it adds increased performance and native JSON support.